# Building the Kernel error

Tags: pi-3b+, kernel, make

I was following the steps defined here
https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html#updating-your-kernel

and when executing this command,  I get the next errors:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/lib/modules/4.9.59+/linux $ sudo make -j4 zImage modules dtbs
  SYNC    include/config/auto.conf.cmd
  UPD     include/config/kernel.release
  UPD     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  UPD     include/generated/bounds.h
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s
  UPD     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CC      arch/arm/mach-bcm/board_bcm2835.o
  CC      arch/arm/vfp/vfpmodule.o
  CC      init/main.o
  CC      kernel/trace/trace_clock.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-bcm/bcm2711.o
  AS      arch/arm/vfp/entry.o
  AS      arch/arm/vfp/vfphw.o
  CC      arch/arm/vfp/vfpsingle.o
  CC      kernel/trace/ftrace.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-bcm/platsmp.o
  CC      arch/arm/vfp/vfpdouble.o
  AR      arch/arm/mach-bcm/built-in.a
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/do_mounts.o
  AR      arch/arm/vfp/built-in.a
  LDS     arch/arm/vdso/vdso.lds
  CC      arch/arm/vdso/vgettimeofday.o
  CC      init/do_mounts_rd.o
  AS      arch/arm/vdso/datapage.o
  CC      arch/arm/vdso/note.o
  LD      arch/arm/vdso/vdso.so.raw
  MUNGE   arch/arm/vdso/vdso.so.dbg
  OBJCOPY arch/arm/vdso/vdso.so
  AS      arch/arm/vdso/vdso.o
  AR      arch/arm/vdso/built-in.a
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/head.o
  LDS     arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/elf.o
  CC      kernel/trace/ring_buffer.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/irq.o
  CC      init/do_mounts_initrd.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/opcodes.o
  CC      init/initramfs.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/process.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/ptrace.o
  CC      kernel/trace/trace.o
  CC      init/calibrate.o
  CC      init/init_task.o
  CC      kernel/trace/trace_output.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/reboot.o
  CC      init/version.o
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/setup.o
  AR      init/built-in.a
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/signal.o
In file included from ./include/linux/atomic.h:84:0,
                 from ./include/asm-generic/bitops/lock.h:5,
                 from ./arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h:243,
                 from ./include/linux/bitops.h:29,
                 from ./include/linux/kernel.h:12,
                 from ./include/asm-generic/bug.h:20,
                 from ./arch/arm/include/asm/bug.h:60,
                 from ./include/linux/bug.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/random.h:10,
                 from arch/arm/kernel/signal.c:8:
./include/linux/atomic-fallback.h: In function ‘atomic_dec_and_test’:
./include/linux/atomic-fallback.h:1136:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘atomic_dec_return’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  return atomic_dec_return(v) == 0;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/sigreturn_codes.o
  CC      kernel/trace/trace_seq.o
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:280: recipe for target 'arch/arm/kernel/signal.o' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/kernel/signal.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC      kernel/trace/trace_stat.o
kernel/trace/trace.c: In function ‘tracing_open’:
kernel/trace/trace.c:4517:12: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
 static int tracing_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
scripts/Makefile.build:280: recipe for target 'kernel/trace/trace.o' failed
make[2]: *** [kernel/trace/trace.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC      certs/system_keyring.o
scripts/Makefile.build:497: recipe for target 'arch/arm/kernel' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/kernel] Error 2
Makefile:1825: recipe for target 'arch/arm' failed
make: *** [arch/arm] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  AS      certs/system_certificates.o
  CC      kernel/cgroup/cgroup.o
  CC      kernel/bpf/core.o
  CC      certs/common.o
scripts/Makefile.build:497: recipe for target 'kernel/trace' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/trace] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC      kernel/cgroup/rstat.o
  AR      certs/built-in.a
  CC      kernel/cgroup/namespace.o
In file included from kernel/cgroup/cgroup.c:40:0:
./include/linux/pagemap.h: In function ‘dir_pages’:
In file included from ./include/linux/if_vlan.h:10:0,
                 from ./include/linux/filter.h:21,
                 from kernel/bpf/core.c:21:
./include/linux/netdevice.h: In function ‘netdev_xmit_more’:
In file included from ./include/vdso/datapage.h:137:0,
                 from ./arch/arm/include/asm/vdso_datapage.h:14,
                 from ./arch/arm/include/asm/elf.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/elf.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/bpf.h:20,
                 from ./include/linux/bpf-cgroup.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/cgroup-defs.h:22,
                 from ./include/linux/cgroup.h:28,
                 from kernel/cgroup/cgroup-internal.h:5,
                 from kernel/cgroup/rstat.c:2:
./arch/arm/include/asm/vdso/gettimeofday.h: In function ‘__arch_get_hw_counter’:
./include/linux/pagemap.h:985:2: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
  return (unsigned long)(inode->i_size + PAGE_SIZE - 1) >>
  ^~~~~~
./include/linux/netdevice.h:4788:2: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
  return __this_cpu_read(softnet_data.xmit.more);
  ^~~~~~
./arch/arm/include/asm/vdso/gettimeofday.h:127:2: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
  if (clock_mode == VDSO_CLOCKMODE_NONE)
  ^~
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
scripts/Makefile.build:280: recipe for target 'kernel/bpf/core.o' failed
make[2]: *** [kernel/bpf/core.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:497: recipe for target 'kernel/bpf' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/bpf] Error 2
  CC      kernel/cgroup/cgroup-v1.o
scripts/Makefile.build:280: recipe for target 'kernel/cgroup/rstat.o' failed
make[2]: *** [kernel/cgroup/rstat.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
scripts/Makefile.build:280: recipe for target 'kernel/cgroup/cgroup.o' failed
make[2]: *** [kernel/cgroup/cgroup.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:497: recipe for target 'kernel/cgroup' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/cgroup] Error 2
Makefile:1825: recipe for target 'kernel' failed
make: *** [kernel] Error 2
```

The hardware I am using is the raspberry pi 3B, kernel version 4.19.66-v7+.

I know there is actually a mismatch between the folder  4.9.59+ I execute the command in, and my current kernel version 4.19.66-v7+. But actually if I am following the directions described in the documentation process, and cd to the linux folder.

```
cd linux
KERNEL=kernel7
make bcm2709_defconfig
```

Among the different ones I have 4.19.66+, 4.19.66-v7+,  4.9.59+ and 4.9.59-v7+. That was the only  one what has it.

My final purpose what I am doing this for, is to get the the source code, since originally, the header files weren´t included.
Any idea about how could I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try to build the current RPF kernel 5.15.18?

Comment: With 5.15.18-v7+ segmentation fault again:

fs/nfs/flexfilelayout/flexfilelayout.c: In function ‘ff_layout_get_ds_info’:
fs/nfs/flexfilelayout/flexfilelayout.c:1972:1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault

kernel/softirq.c: In function ‘__do_softirq’:
kernel/softirq.c:255:43: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
 asmlinkage __visible void __softirq_entry __do_softirq(void)

Comment: Now you can report the error at https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux because you're running on a current kernel.